# iNotes on any version of Internet Explorer is emulating IE9

Tags: ajax, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am customizing iNotes (Notes web mail client), adding some features using javascript that require ajax calls to external sources.  In doing so I have found Internet Explorer won't perform CORS (cross-origin) requests. Errors are either access denied or some other security errors depending on how it's called.  Chrome and FF and Safari all work.

I have found what I believe to be the culprit, iNotes adds a meta-tag to emulate IE9.

```
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

For CORS requests, IE9 does not support XMLHttpRequest, rather you must use XDomainRequest, which was only supported in IE8 and IE9.  Since it's emulating IE9, the XMLHttpRequest (or jQuery .ajax calls for that matter) don't work.

I have not been able to find any way to remove that meta tag, I did a search on the mail file and there are no matches for IE=EmulateIE9 that I could find.  And I'm sure if I did remove it, I would break something in iNotes.

I didn't want to load jQuery, but may do so for this script and include the moonscript plugin which uses XDR for ie8 and ie9 browsers.  If iNotes is ever updated, it will still work.

Anyone else run into this problem and find a better solution?

Comment: Which version of inotes?

Comment: mail (R9) template, mail9.ntf

Comment: No, I asked for the version of iNotes: Which formsX.nsf do you have on the server?

Comment: Forms9.nsf, but there is also a Forms9s.nsf in the directory.  When I looked that up it says that I have to enable to address"quirks mode", or in other words, to run in standard mode I enable Forms9s in the notes.ini.  I also hae iNotesExt_9.nsf, which is where I have the customization files for iNotes.

Comment: That was it, Lothar, SP5 added Forms9s which eliminates ie9 emulation.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lothar Mueller pointed me in the right direction.

Domino 9.0.1 Fix Pack 5 adds a Forms9s.nsf which allows you to get rid of "Quirks Mode" for IE backwards compatibility.  After installing the FP, the new forms9s.nsf file is installed, then you update the notes.ini with

```
iNotes_WA_DefaultFormsFile=iNotes/Forms9s.nsf
iNotes_WA_FormsFiles=iNotes/Forms9s.nsf
```

and it eliminates the emulation tag for IE.  I still have to test my iNotes customization apps, but this gives an option for running some IE features that didn't work before such as Ajax requests from iNotesExt_9.nsf, etc.

Comment: After a very quick/brief testing of Forms9s.nsf I found that it fixed the ie9 emulation problem, but right away noticed that you can't do type-aheads in iNotes.  If you have $inbox sorted by user, you cannot start typing a name to go to first instance.  Doesn't work for any of the columns.  That's a big bug.